# AndroidStudio 4.1 Problem with Sourcesets

Tags: android-studio

```
AndroidStudio version: 4.1
Device: MacBook Pro  MacOs 10.15.7
```

- Step1: new a example project
- Step2: new a module named mylibrary
- Step3: create 'api' dir at mylibrary/src/main
- Step4: modify build.gradle in app as followed

```
android {
    ...
    sourceSets{
        main{
            java.srcDirs "${rootDir}/mylibrary/src/main/api"
        }
    }
}
```

mylibrary cannot recognize java file!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had loads of issues with the new android 4.1 update I then updated the version to Android Studio 4.1 RC 2 https://developer.android.com/studio/archive the link to the download is there give it a try if it don't work just go back to 4.0